# Best way to search a list of 10,000 words in long text in T-SQL? Cursor is too slow and fails due with Memory Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of 10,000 words (rows) with format NVARCHAR(20) that I need to search in another table (mymessagetable) with long text (i.e. NVARCHAR(MAX)) in T-SQL (SQL Server 2012). The size of mymessagetable can be between 30k to 100k. I need to know what is the best way to search these key words in a list of long message that is mymessagetable.

Right now I am using a cursor and it works well with small table like 4000. But as I put in table with 10k rows, it gives memory error after few thousands searches. Even the result is zero rows return. In future I might have a bigger list like 100k and i won't be having zero rows return always. Is there a better way to get this job done. I was thinking to have a where clause to break this task in chunks but this will be manual work.

SQL command I am using in the cursor (that is loop of my words list(10k))

```
SELECT message from mymessagetable where message like '%mytext%'
```

Why I am doing this:
I am trying to check if these messages from mymessagetable has anything to do with my list of keys.

Comment: Please explain with some sample data

Comment: also tag the version of sql sever you are using

Comment: Sure I will add some data. Although I need to create one :). So It will take some time

Comment: "Memory error" says you need to update your sql server/apply some service pack.

Comment: Well my main question is if there is any way other than using cursor at all. If no then memory error is something i need to work on

Comment: @IvanStarostin incorrect. The memory error is more likely thrown in management studio due to it not  being able to handle/buffer that many returned resultsets.

Comment: What is the word separator in the long text? Presumably you don't want to match partial words, e.g. "engage" is not a match for "disengaged".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a cursor should be the first sign that something is wrong!

You can do this set-based:

```
SELECT mymessagetable.message
     , mywords.word
FROM   mymessagetable
 INNER
  JOIN mywords
    ON mymessagetable.message LIKE '%' + mywords.word + '%'
;
```

Comment: This is the best approach given what little information OP gave us, but performance is still going to be poor.

Comment: Looks something I was looking for. Let me try and come back to you

Comment: @ta.speot.is yep - LIKE comparisons with a leading wildcard are always going to be terrible for performance. Really should be looking in to something like Full-Text Indexing.

Comment: Yes it works and in comparison with cursor the performance is almost 50% better. I will be definitely looking for full-Text indexing